# How to append Bootstrap tooltip element to specified element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, angular-ui

Due to Bootstrap tooltips sticking when the element that triggers it is removed from the DOM (See https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3647 and https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2298), I want to have the tooltip element appened to an element I know is getting removed when I'm having this problem in my app. The [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips) mentions a `container` option, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm not sure exactly what to put as the value. I tried making the string a jQuery selector (e.g. "#MY_ELEMENT_ID"), but it kept appending the tooltip to the body. What value is this option expecting?

As a side note, I'm setting this option through [Angular-UI](http://angular-ui.github.com/). So, like this:

```
myModule.value('ui.config', {
    jq: {
        tooltip: {
            placement: "bottom",
            container: "#MY_ELEMENT_ID"
        }
    }
});
```

Other options are working as expected when setting through Angular-UI, so I don't think the problem is in there. I'm just not sure what to set as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got back to looking at this, and it turns out we were using an older version of bootstrap that didn't have this option. I upgraded to the latest version, and it now works just as expected. My apologies for not noticing that before posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing a custom implementation that removes the tooltip when the scope is destroyed (you can listen for that even to be broadcasted).

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
  // unload tooltip
});
```